# application is not using the correct connection string

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, app-config

In app config file. I used initial catalog ='jana' as database name.
 Then i run it use it for some times.

Then later i changed initial catalog ='siva' as database name . That i changed database name alone and saved it. Whenever i run this 'siva' as initial catalog , select queries is using 'siva' database at the same time inserting /updating queries using my previous database 'jana'. Its really weird.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: rebuild your application and check

Comment: what exactly your problem .

Answer (score 0):

thanks for considering my query. I rectified mistake by myself. 
                 Actually while inserting/updating queries , i have used databasename.dbo.tablename for all queries. That is the cause whenever i used different database , the one which i used on creating was always affected.
 Hope u understand my scenario. 
Thanks for all.